# How to give background colour for TextBlock in windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, textblock

```
Using Windows Phone 8.1
```

I have 4 textblocks stacked into a vertical stackpanel. I want the background colour of the tapped textblock to change to blue. How can it be done.

Or is it advisable to use list view. But then how to override the normal click of list item to the one I require.

Answer (score 0):

The TextBlock itself always draws transparently. To show a background colour place it on another control which does show a colour.

If you want each TextBlock to colour separately then putting each one in a Border is a likely choice.

If I understand what you're aiming for though I'd use a ToggleButton rather than a bare TextBlock. You can style the ToggleButton to look however you'd like while still maintaining the basic toggle behaviour that it sounds like you want.

If you want to use a ListView then you can handle the ItemClick event and look at the arguments to see which item was clicked, or you could handle the click for each item in the template itself. For a constant four buttons I probably wouldn't use a ListView. I would choose a ListView if I have several like items to bind to from code behind.